# Dereferencing char * array[] and storing in char ** array[] (C)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

**Edit. Sorry for the minimal information included previously**

Say I have the following code:

```
    char ** a[16];
    a[15] = '\0';

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        char * b[3];
        b[2] = '\0';

        b[0] = "foo";
        b[1] = "bar";

        if (i == 4) {
            b[0] = "hello";
            b[1] = "world";
        }

        a[i] = b;
    }
```

Straight after the for loop, if I include the following two lines:

```
printf("%s %s\n", a[0][0], a[0][1]);
printf("%s %s\n", a[4][0], a[4][1]);
```

I want the output to be:

```
foo bar
hello world
```

However it is instead:

```
hello world
hello world
```

I am aware this is because of my declaration, `a[i] = b;`, where b is an array of char pointers. Each loop, the character pointers pointed to by b[0] and b[1] are changed.

In the final loop they are set to "hello" and "world" respectively. Since I assigned b to a[i], every index of a now points to the same thing.

What I would like to do is dereference b, such that a[i] is given the value b points to rather than b itself. Therefore after the loop all indexes of a are not the same.

I tried using the following but both resulted in segmentation faults:

`*a[i] = *b`
and
`**a[i] = **b`

Any help would be much appreciated, as I'm totally lost. Thank you :)

Comment: Please show the exact code in question, or a [mcve]. The explanation doesn’t really give enough information on what’s happening. Assignment assigns the value of the variable, it doesn’t reference the variable in any way. So when `b` changes value nothing in the array changes.

Comment: I suggest reading an entry-level tutorial on arrays and pointers in C.  That would be more productive than posting fragments of buggy code that you don't understand.

Comment: My apologies. I have edited the question and included an example. The reason I'm using **[] is because the goal of my actual program is to read a list of commands from a file and then make use of pipe(), dup2() and execvp() to pipe them like so:
cmd1 | cmd2 | ... | cmdn.

Comment: Also, don't use `'\0'` as a null pointer.  It's intended to be used as the null character, not a null pointer, so it's misleading. Again, read a tutorial.  Learn about pointers, and arrays, and characters.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to do is dereference b, such that a[i] is given the value b points to rather than b itself. Therefore after the loop all indexes of a are not the same.

Note that b itself is an array, so you cannot just assign `value b points to rather than b itself` because b does not point to a single value.

To really do this (not sure why you would want this) replace the line:

> a[i] = b;

```
a[i][0] = b[0];
a[i][1] = b[1];
a[i][2] = b[2];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :). I tried what you suggested, but unfortunately I got a segfault

Comment: Yeah, because before calling those lines, you have to allocate memory  for a[i]:
a[i] = malloc(3*sizeof(char *))